# Portugal - snorkeling and fishing

Tags: diving, portugal, fishing

I would like to go snorkeling and maybe fishing to Portugal. I've read that it is not good to do these things on the western portugal because there are big waves and cold water. So I've decided after reading an article that it could be fine to go somewhere to the Southern Portugal (somewhere next to Algarve).

My question is:

Are there good places to snorkeling somewhere at the Southern Portugal?

Are there fish we could fishing or is it like Croatia - only small fish?

EDIT: As far as I'm concerned, it is legal to fishing in the Sea/Ocean there, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Cold water is all relative, where I live anything above 16C is considered warm, under 12C is considered cold :)

North western shore of Portugal (Viana do Castelo) is about 16C - 19C (60F - 66F) 
South eastern shore of Portugal (Tavira) is about 20C - 24C (69F - 74F)

Algarve region of Portugal definitely seems to be the best part to do snorkeling, especially if you are not used to big waves and currents. But as always the best thing is to do some research on the internet on various areas and then contact a few tourist/scuba places in and around the area you are thinking of traveling too to see what is on offer. Might even be a good idea to go with these schools to learn the safe spots.

As for fishing that would depend on what kind of fishing you wish to do, but looking at this site there is definitely scope for some fishing: [Fishing Portugal](http://www.portugal-sport-and-adventure.com/fishing-portugal.html)

Some temperatures can be seen here:

[Albufeira Sea Temperature](http://www.seatemperature.org/europe/portugal/albufeira.htm)

[Algarve: Annual Weather Averages](http://www.holiday-weather.com/algarve/averages/)

Comment: Do you have any authoritative references for the temperatures you quote?

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://bfy.tw/1Ixm